# Positioning about me section on my website

Tags: html, css, pug, stylus

The link to my website is:   [mckelvey.me:1122](http://mckelvey.me:1122) . I am having trouble positioning my About Me section. It has a image that wont scale properly, and should be full height of #about and on the left side with a width of about 40%. and the title and paragragh needs to be centered horizontally and vertically on the right side the width of the rest.

Note the code is in jade and stylus, you can answer in html and css if you like they are super close anyways:

```
.about
    min-height 50vh
    background #1F7D5B
    color #f7f7f7
  h1
      font-size 1.5em
      font-weight 600
      color #232323
      text-align center
      padding .5em 0
      float right
      width 100%

  p
      font-size 1em
      font-weight 100
      max-width 50em
      text-align center
      line-height 150%

  img
      float left
      width 18em
      height 18em

.wrap
    float right
```

The jade/html is:

```
 #about
  .about
    img(src="/img/abstract.jpg")
    .wrap
      h1 About Me
      p Hello, I'm a Designer, Front-end Developer and of course a Tea Enthusiast. It is my mission to program simple and elegant, responsive websites while under the influence of tea.
```

Comment: You're more than welcome to create a generic example of your code to help anyone wishing to answer avoid the hassle of going onto your website to analyse your code. It can be simply, a minimal solution in the area where you believe the problem lies. JSFiddle provides a great platform to represent this.

Comment: Thats a clear example, I love the tea euphemism also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather difficult to do without you showing the code you used directly so I'll try and break this down piece by piece.

---

To fix the image fully not fitting the div you can add the following to your CSS:

```
#about img { width:40%; max-height:100%; }
```

Adding this tells any image in the id (#) about to be 40% the width ( as you specified ), then make the height proportionate to it.

---

To align the text within your div you need to add two things:

Adding `#about h1, p { vertical-align:middle; }` to your CSS tells it to align centered along the vertical axis within your div.

To align the next horizontally you would need to add:

```
#about h1, p {padding-left:auto; padding-right:auto;}
```

This tells the `h1` and `p` elements you used to align in the middle on your div.

**Sidenote:** This may lead to your text overflowing out of your div so add the `text align` property to your CSS to fix this. Example: `text-align:justify;`.

---

This is the best explanation possible without the full code and what you specified, hope this helped.

Comment: I added ` width:40%; max-height:100%;` but it ended up making the image overflow. I added the code for the about me section in the question, does this change anything?

Comment: Try adding `max-height:100%; max-width:100%;` to your CSS instead. This will tell the browser to resize it as much as possible proportionately without extending the max width and height.

Comment: Tried it here is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/AhwlgYq The other sections around it like the header and skills sections is positioned by flex-box. Just in case if that makes a difference. i also have the about me section height at min-height: 50vh;

Comment: Did you add the width and the height properties to the image without the parent div? Make sure you added `.about img{...}` or `#about img {...}` (which ever one you used).

Comment: yup: `.about img{...}` I do have a id about above the class about though see code in question. I used the class about for styltlying and used the id about for the menu.

Comment: okay I fixed the image issue by just saying `height: 50vh;` instead of `min-height:50vh;` in .about class.